# Why does np.zeros_like(x) result in a different array than np.zeros(len(x))?

Tags: python, numpy

My code behaves differently when I use `np.zeros(len(x))` vs. `np.zeros_like(x)`

With `np.zeros(len(x))`, I get the correct answer:

```py
def discount_cumsum(x: np.ndarray, d):
    # if i use the following line, it works
    y = np.zeros(len(x))

    y[-1] = x[-1]
    for i in range(len(x) - 2, -1, -1):
        y[i] = x[i] + d * y[i + 1]
    return y

discount_cumsum(range(5), 0.5) # array([1.625, 3.25 , 4.5  , 5.   , 4.   ])
```

Switching to `np.zeros_like(x)` gives the wrong answer:

```
def discount_cumsum_2(x: np.ndarray, d):
    # if i use the following line, it doesn't work
    y = np.zeros_like(x)

    y[-1] = x[-1]
    for i in range(len(x) - 2, -1, -1):
        y[i] = x[i] + d * y[i + 1]
    return y

discount_cumsum_2(range(5), 0.5) # array([1, 3, 4, 5, 4])
```

I expect `np.zeros_like(x)` and `np.zeros(len(x))` to give same results. Why do I get different results?

---

for anyone interested, this is what i wanted at the beginning

```py
@numba.njit
def discount_cumsum(x: np.ndarray, d):
    y = x.copy().astype(np.float32)
    for i in range(len(y) - 2, -1, -1):
        y[i] += d * y[i + 1]
    return y
```

Comment: If `zeros_like` and `zeros` gave the same results, why would there be two different functions?

Comment: @PaulH - Because they give you the same results under some conditions. For a 1D array, it should be the same ... ignoring potentially different dtypes of course.

Comment: @tdelaney I don’t follow. Which question are you answering?

Comment: @PaulH - commenting on your odd comment that a library wouldn't expose two different functions that _sometimes_ return the same values. OP thought these two functions would return the same result with the given inputs.

Comment: @tdelaney
Maybe I’m blinded by my familiarity with numpy, but with any library my default expectation would be that functions with different names would have different behaviors even if some overlap exists.

Comment: Did you go back and reread the function docs?  What do they say about `dtype`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.zeros_like` gives you an array of zeros with the *same `dtype`* as the argument<sup>1</sup>. When you pass it `range(5)`, `zeros_like` creates an array of `int`s. This is the crucial difference from `np.zeros(len(x))`, which gives you an array of `float`s of the same length of `x`.

```
>>> a = range(5)
>>> x = np.zeros_like(a)
>>> y = np.zeros(len(a))

>>> print(x.dtype, y.dtype)
int32 float64
```

Since your function now has `y` as an array of *integers*, any operations on it are integer operations and you lose whatever precision you could have had if you had an array of floats.

If you want to force `y` to be an array of floats all the time, you can do:

```
y = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=np.float64)
```

Alternatively, you can use `np.zeros` with `x.shape` (of course, you'll have to ensure `x` is a numpy array first):

```
y = np.zeros(np.asarray(x).shape)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If the argument is not a `np.ndarray` (and therefore has no `dtype`), it is converted to a `np.ndarray` before its `dtype` is used to create the array of zeros. In the example from [@tdelaney's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77325070/why-does-np-zeros-likex-result-in-a-different-array-than-np-zeroslenx/77325126?noredirect=1#comment136321466_77325126), `np.zeros_like([1, 2.1, 'three'])` first converts `[1, 2.1, 'three']` to an `array(['1', '2.1', 'three'], dtype='<U32')`, and then returns an array of "zeros" of `dtype='<U32'` (i.e. empty strings)

Comment: And to be clear, its not the dtype of the argument (e.g., `range`) but the contained values. And it can be surprising when you mix types in the contained values. `np.zeros_like([1,2.1,'three'])` isn't even zeros.

Comment: @tdelaney right, it is the dtype of the argument _converted to a `np.array`_ (because a list or a range has no dtype). `np.array([1, 2.1, 'three'])` -> `array(['1', '2.1', 'three'], dtype='<U32')`, so `np.zeros([1, 2.1, 'three'])`  gives an array of "zeros" of dtype `'<U32'` (which are empty strings). I edited my answer to clarify this